# Lookahead assertion with multiple values

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following text:

```
[red]

aaa [bbb] hello

[blue]

aaa

[green]

ccc
```

I want to extract all the texts between the section headers. I tried lookahead assertion that matches from a particular section header until another header from a list of headers:

```
keys = ('red', 'blue', 'green')
for key in keys:
    match = re.search(r'\[' + key + r'\](.*)(?=(?:' + '|'.join(keys) + r'|$))',
                      text, flags=re.DOTALL)

    print(key, match.group(1))
```

I'm missing something though since it doesn't match anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `.*?` instead of `.*` help? See https://regex101.com/r/1RZ2rF/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided not to use a regex *for matching the section contents*:

```
# Walk through the file line by line and collect text from the specific sections
keys = ('red', 'blue', 'green')
last_section = ''
for line in text.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('#'):
        continue

    match = re.match(r'^\[(' + '|'.join(keys) + ')\]', line)
    if match:
        last_section = match.group(1)
        continue

    if last_section:
        new_contents[last_section] += '\n' + line

for section in new_contents:
    new_contents[section] = new_contents[section].strip()
```

Comment: You are using regex even though you say otherwise... re.match is part of pythons regular expressions operations.

Comment: Sorry, I meant without having the regex parse out the section contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can regex findall! You can group you section and the values in it together like,

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.findall(r'\[(\w*)\]([\w \n]*)',text)
[('red', '\n\naaa '), ('bbb', ' hello\n\n'), ('blue', '\n\naaa\n\n'), ('green', '')]
```

here for your section `\[(\w*)\]` and `([\w \n]*)` for the contents in your section. With that result in hand, you can strip or replace the redundant newlines!

Hope it helps!

Comment: That will also make `[bbb]` into a separate group though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something such as this approach could work:

```
keys = ('red', 'blue', 'green')

res = re.findall(r'\[\w+\].?|([\w\[\] ]+)', text)
res = [x for x in res if x]

for n in range(len(keys)):
    print(keys[n], res[n])
```

Result:

```
('red', 'aaa [bbb] hello')
('blue', 'aaa')
('green', 'ccc')
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/p55ckh/1

Comment: I only want to find sections based on the defined keys though. So if there is a section `[pink]`, it should be considered a part of the text of the preceding valid section header.

Comment: What's the difference in doing that way or by group? If `[red]` is section 1, then it gets the text from section 1... The lookahead really isn't needed. You should be able to adapt this example to do it the way you've mentioned also. The key thing is how the regex is capturing what is between the sections I think.

Comment: It matters because if I append `[pink]\n\nbbb` to the example text and run it through your regex, it will not include this string in the `green` key's value.

Answer (score 0):

A string handling method, no matter the order of your key in text. If you do not want to use regex, hope it helps!

```
text = '[red]\naaa [bbb] hello\n[blue]\naaa\n[green]\nccc'

# keys = ('red', 'blue', 'green')
# keys = ('blue', 'red', 'green')
# keys = ('green', 'red', 'blue')
keys = ('green', 'blue', 'red')
# store key and index of key tuple
index_key_tuples = []

for key in keys:
    index = text.find('[' + key + ']')
    if index != -1:
        index_key_tuples.append((index, key))
# sort the index key tuple
index_key_tuples.sort()

i = 0
size = len(index_key_tuples)
while i < size - 1:
    # start index of content of key
    item = index_key_tuples[i]
    key = item[1]
    start_index = item[0] + len(key) + 2  # 2 is for square bracket
    # end index of content of key
    next_item = index_key_tuples[i + 1]
    end_index = next_item[0]
    # content of key
    key_content = text[start_index:end_index].strip()
    print(key, key_content)
    i += 1

# handle the last key
last_item = index_key_tuples[size-1]
key = last_item[1]
start_index = last_item[0] + len(key) + 2
key_content = text[start_index:].strip()
print(key, key_content)
```